# Expressing $x^{2}-y^{2}-y + i \cdot (2xy+y)$ in terms of $z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

How to express the following expression $$x^{2}-y^{2}-y + i \cdot (2xy+y)$$ in terms of $z$.

$x^{2}-y^{2} + 2xyi = (x+iy)^{2}=z^{2}$ but what about $iy -y$.

Comment: *Hint:* $y=\Im(z)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry i don't get it. I want it to express this expression in terms of $z$. So i am not sure if $\mathfrak{J}(z)$ will work.

Comment: The above might seem like a cheat, but note that you can't always get around using $\Re$ or $\Im$ -- if you could, then presumably you could write $f(z) = y$ as some algebraic polynomial in $z$, but then $f(z)$ would be analytic which it is clearly not. 
edit: another thing is $2\Re(z) = z + \overline{z}$.

Comment: $y=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\bar{z})=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\frac{|z|^2}{z})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ x^2-y^2+i(2xy) +iy-y= z^2 + (i-1)\Im(z) =z^2 + \frac1{2i}(i-1)(z-z^*)  $$